# Understanding matrix norm and quadratic equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

Suppose I have two quadratic expressions

$$(a - b)^2$$ and $$(a-c)^2$$

where $a, b, c$ are real numbers, then I think the following holds:

$$(a - b)^2 < (a - c)^2$$

iff $|a - b| < |a - c|$.

Now suppose I have two expressions in matrix form:

$$((A - B)v)^T((A-B)v)$$
$$((A - C)v)^T((A-C)v)$$

where $A, B, C$ are $m\times n$ real matrices, and $v$ is a $n\times 1$ vector. In this case,
when does $$((A - B)v)^T((A-B)v) < ((A - C)v)^T((A-C)v)$$
hold? I was thinking that the above will hold if
$$\|A - B\| < \|A - C\|$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the Frobenius norm. However, I am not sure if this is correct. Is it correct to approach this by measuring the "similarity" between $A$ and $B$ using a matrix norm? If so, is the Frobenius norm the correct choice?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo not equations, sorry. changed to expressions instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Frobenius norm of a matrix is the sum of all squared elements from the matrix. To obtain the Frobenius norm you choose $v$ to be a vector of ones.

But I think you want to allow $v$ be any real valued vector. If $A-B$ and $A-C$ are positive definite then you can create following norm $||M||_v=v^TM^TMv=(Mv)^TMv$ where $M$ is some $m\times n$ matrix and your idea holds.

EDIT: I am not allowed to comment yet, so I edit. Anyways, insert A-B and A-C where M is in the suggested definition of norm. Instead of M use $||A-B||_v<||A-C||_v$. Remember A-B and A-C need to be positive definite too.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix

If they are not positive definite or if you cannot know if they are positive definite, then we need another norm.

Comment: Thanks. What is $M$ in relation to $A, B,$ and $C$?

Comment: I do not know whether $A-B$ or $A-C$ is positive definite. They may or may not be.